# This tag is ambiguous; should we re[moveit]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

It looks like [moveit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moveit) is being used for at least two different things, so I'm bringing it up to Meta per [How should ambiguous tags be dealt with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/how-should-ambiguous-tags-be-dealt-with).

This tag was initially used for [ipswitch's (now Progress') MOVEit](https://www.ipswitch.com/moveit), but within a week was also used for a question about the robotics-related [MoveIt Motion Planning Framework](https://moveit.ros.org/) by ROS.

The tag has no guidance and no wiki.

There's only 47 questions with this tag, so:

- 39 appear to be related to robotics/ROS MoveIt, and are also tagged [ros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ros).
- 8 appear to be for ipswitch's MOVEit.

How should this ambiguous tag be handled? [ros-moveit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ros-moveit) for the robotics usage, and leave [moveit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moveit) for MOVEit?

ipswitch's MOVEit does have specific modules that could be part of the tag as well (such as `moveit-automation`), but as they're written I haven't used MOVEit enough to know what the name of the tool was when the older questions were asked.

Comment: Now it's time to think of a pun :)

Comment: The vast majority of the questions seem to be related to ROS (and are also tagged [tag:ros]), so leaving the original tag for MOVEit seems like a bad idea; the tag would still be misused for questions about ROS. I'd suggest `moveit-file-transfer` for the other tag name. That said, with only 8 questions (not all of which actually meet SO's standards, I think), is there actually a need for a tag with this meaning?

Comment: I like to `moveit`, `moveit`

Comment: @kaya3 1) thanks for your edits, especially to the title. :D 2) the reason I found the tag was because I was looking to see if any questions about MOVEit Automation (one of the 'modules') were on SO, or if a different network site would be better, as I've got a question I want to ask about logic options. I didn't check the quality of the questions, but maybe these belong over on SU ... ? There's really just not a lot on any of the SE sites.

Comment: @Thum Choon Tat  Working of yours they could also rename the post:   I'd like to moveit, `moveit`

Comment: @ThumChoonTat thanks, now I feel old...

Comment: @Braiam what do you mean? That song [makes me feel young](https://youtu.be/hdcTmpvDO0I)

Comment: @DanielWiddis kids these days, don't know the history. I was about a wee bit old when it came out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuo8kD5zF5I